# Retrieving ParseFile from ParseUser

Tags: file, parse-platform

I am trying to get ParseFile from ParseUser. I am able to upload file (picture avatar) to ParseUser, but I have nullPointerException when I want to get this picture back. Here is my method. Any ideas?

```
public void getUserData() {
ParseUser myParseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

/* textviews work great */ 
usernameTextView.setText(myParseUser.getUsername());
titleTextView.setText(myParseUser.getString("Title"));
nameTextView.setText(myParseUser.getString("Name"));
surnameTextView.setText(myParseUser.getString("Surname"));
emailTextView.setText(myParseUser.getString("email"));

/* on next line I get error */
ParseFile imageFile = (ParseFile) myParseUser.get("Picture");
imageFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
 if (e == null) {
   pictureBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
   avatarImageView.setImageBitmap(pictureBitMap);
} else {
   // something went wrong
} } });  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with custom columns. Need to fetch the user with myParseUser.fetch(); so you can get the picture column.